# Is this approach to generate an access token alright?

Tags: security, access-token, websecurity

Firstly, I am generating a random password

```
b := make([]byte, length)
if _, err := rand.Read(b); err != nil {
   return "", err
}

return hex.EncodeToString(b), nil
```

and then generating an access token like this

```
const (
    // The draft RFC(https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03#section-9.3) recommends
    // the following time and memory cost as sensible defaults.
    timeCost    = 1
    memoryCost  = 64 * 1024
    parallelism = 4
    keyLength   = 20
    saltLength  = 12
)


saltRaw := make([]byte, saltLength)
if _, err := rand.Read(saltRaw); err != nil {
    return "", err
}
salt := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(saltRaw)

hash := argon2.IDKey([]byte(password), []byte(salt), timeCost, memoryCost, parallelism, keyLength)
encodedHash := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(hash)
```

The encoded hash is then saved to db and the user is returned this access token

```
return fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s.%d.%d.%d", password, salt, timeCost, memoryCost, parallelism)
```

Looks something like this

```
54fbe184a03529fd50bfd94013ea0085.spNfo8WetBmdBxfZ.1.65536.4
```

I am not really liking the looks of the access token. base64 encoding doesn't produce an appealing result as well

```
NTRmYmUxODRhMDM1MjlmZDUwYmZkOTQwMTNlYTAwODUuc3BOZm84V2V0Qm1kQnhmWi4xLjY1NTM2
LjQK
```

but anyway, that's not a big concern at all.

When a user makes a request with that access token

- I am simply splitting the token by "."
- then generating the argon2 hash again
- and then doing a db lookup to see if that token exists

I couldn't find any articles that talk about how they generate an access token.

Comment: This question may be a better suited for https://security.stackexchange.com/. I glossed over the details and I'm no security expert but I feel like your approach could work. However, for access tokens, using an expensive hash function like Argon2 may be unnecessary. It's usually fine to use something fast like SHA-256.

Comment: I recommend looking at Api Security in Action book: https://www.manning.com/books/api-security-in-action It's really excellent and discusses various types of tokens (specifically chapter 5) including the code in detail. Chapter 5 code is in this branch https://github.com/NeilMadden/apisecurityinaction/tree/chapter05-end - notably HmacTokenStore (https://github.com/NeilMadden/apisecurityinaction/blob/chapter05-end/natter-api/src/main/java/com/manning/apisecurityinaction/token/HmacTokenStore.java#L21-L37) which delegates to DatabaseTokenStore.

Comment: I think of most interest, is section 5.3.2 in the book called "Authenticating tokens with HMAC". - it shows how HMAC can protect against fake token injection and timing attacks.